WebDriverError: unknown error: failed to create Chrome process even when chromedriver, google chrome, selenium are installed
My package.json looks like this:

{
    "name": "hello",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "main.js",
    "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^30.0.6",
        "electron-chromedriver": "^29.4.0",
        "selenium-webdriver": "^4.21.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron ."
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "chromedriver": "^125.0.0"
    }
}

I have all of them in one folder, and another .js file containing my Selenium code. I tried using the sample code on the Electron website, but it's not working.
`const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')
const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  // The "9515" is the port opened by ChromeDriver.
  .usingServer('http://localhost:9515')
  .withCapabilities({
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
      // Here is the path to your Electron binary.
      binary: '/Path-to-Your-App.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron'
    }
  })
  .forBrowser('chrome') // note: use .forBrowser('electron') for selenium-webdriver <= 3.6.0
  .build()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver')
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click()
driver.wait(() => {
  return driver.getTitle().then((title) => {
    return title === 'webdriver - Google Search'
  })
}, 1000)
driver.quit()`

Above is the sample from the Electron website, the binary line is confusing. I have a chrome.exe inside the same directory, and if I put "./" in the binary location, it gives this error:
WebDriverError: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.
if I put the path of electron in binary like this:
binary: './node_modules/.bin/electron'
I still get the same error.
What should the value of "binary" be?
For added information, my Google Chrome version is 125, which is the same as the chromedriver version. Once ChromeDriver is running, I keep this terminal, and open another terminal and try to run the .js file with the sample Selenium code I mentioned above. (It's the same code in the example of Electron website)
